# divclass:hover + divclass2 - not working

Tags: html, css, background, hover

[Here is a JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SteveDavies/kwpw39ow/)

When I float over the entire size of the panel, img height+text area height, I want the text area (gray) to change to pink, and the transparency of the title to be 100%.

I can do them individually but not he same.  I have read some answers and think

```
divclass:hover + divclass2 {background-color:...;}
```

Might be the answer but I can't get it to work.

Can you help?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sx-12">
    <a href="#" class="box-link " id="">
      <div class="row sm-gutter">
        <div class="img-panel" id="img1">
          <div class="panel-title-bg">
            <div class="panel-title-text" id="panel-text-area-efftct">
              <h3><span>Title &raquo;</span></h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-txt-area">
          <p>blablablabla</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sx-12">
    <a href="#" class="box-link" id="#">
      <div class="row sm-gutter">
        <div class="img-panel" id="img2">
          <div class="panel-title-bg">
            <div class="panel-title-text">
              <h3><span>Title &raquo;</span></h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-txt-area">
          <p>blablablabla.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel-txt-area {
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  color: #424a52;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.panel-txt-area:hover {
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-color: #d10373;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.panel-title-bg {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -190px;
}

.panel-title-bg span {
   background-color: rgba(209,3,115,.6); /*#d10373; */
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.panel-title-bg span:hover{
     background-color: rgba(209,3,115,1.0);

}


.img-panel {
    height: 250px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#img1:hover + panel-text-area-efftct{
  background-color:#d10373;
}


#img1 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-700-430-1.jpg);
}

#img2 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/fashion-q-c-700-430-3.jpg);
}
```

Comment: This question is a bit difficult to understand, you mean when you hover over the grey box, you want the other to become transparent?

Comment: Hi @TheLimeTrees, sorry for not being clear - when I hover over the image area - I want the background of the grey box to be pink, and the title background to be 1.0 in transparancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your css:

Change this:

```
.panel-txt-area:hover {
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-color: #d10373;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

to this:

```
.box-link:hover .panel-txt-area,
.panel-txt-area:hover {
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-color: #d10373;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
```

and change this:

```
.panel-title-bg span:hover{
     background-color: rgba(209,3,115,1.0);

}
```

to this:

```
.box-link:hover .panel-title-bg span,
.panel-title-bg span:hover{
     background-color: rgba(209,3,115,1.0);

}
```

All we are doing is adding an additional hover state when you hover over the .box-link anchor!

**UPDATE**

I guess technically you don't need your original hover states as you won't be able to do them individually anymore... so you can remove .panel-txt-area:hover and .panel-title-bg span:hover if you'd like...

Comment: Hi, @Daniel C this is very close - it has removed the background colour of the <span>Title</span>. I needed that like it was.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's interesting as when I tested it the background of the <span> turns solid (100% opacity) pink... isn't that the desire?  But since you accepted this answer, I assume it all worked out?

Comment: Hi Daniel yes, but when I am not hovering, I need <span>Title to be around 80% opacity, it has removed the <span> background - it has got me close so far, I will have to play more

Comment: Got it working - thanks so much for your help - can I ask how you did this?  To help me thinking - only if you have time

Comment: You need to think about css in more of a parent -> child relationship.  Any elements inside another element can be targeted by it's parent element.  If the element in question is outside of the element you want to target, then you most likely won't be able to target it without assistance (jQuery, for example).  So in your case, I just kept moving up the ancestor chain until I found a common element, which was the anchor tag.  Perfect for hover state!  When that element is hovered, I can now target the child elements!  Make sense?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it doesn't but I will think it through.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have some incorrect naming structures in your CSS.

- No class or ID indicator on `panel-text-area-efftct`
- Selecting the wrong element to be adding the background change on

---

Try changing out

```
#img1:hover + panel-text-area-efftct{
  background-color:#d10373;
}
```

For this and add a new selector

```
.img-panel:hover .panel-title-bg span,
.img-panel:hover ~ .panel-txt-area {
     background-color: rgba(209,3,115,1.0);
}
```

This should also work across all the images & text areas and not on just the first one.

Full Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwpw39ow/3/)

Comment: Hi @Stewatside - not quite what I was after, it also needs to change the background of blablabla background to pink. Thank you thought!

Comment: @SteveDavies have a look at my amended code & example, should get you the desired look.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I still need the <span>Title</span> to not be transparent when I roll over the blablabla area -  I will have to think this through.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwpw39ow/1/)

your code is as it is, i have just added jquery function for your desired effect.

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sx-12">
    <a href="#" class="box-link " id="">
      <div class="row sm-gutter">
        <div class="img-panel" id="img1">
          <div class="panel-title-bg">
            <div class="panel-title-text" id="panel-text-area-efftct">
              <h3><span>Title &raquo;</span></h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-txt-area">
          <p>blablablabla</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sx-12">
    <a href="#" class="box-link" id="#">
      <div class="row sm-gutter">
        <div class="img-panel" id="img2">
          <div class="panel-title-bg">
            <div class="panel-title-text">
              <h3><span>Title &raquo;</span></h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-txt-area">
          <p>blablablabla.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery function :

```
$(".img-panel").hover(function(){
$(".panel-title-text").css("opacity","0");
$(".panel-txt-area").css("background-color","pink");
});
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: jQuery isn't required for everything and you can get in pretty bad habits if you have to jQuery everything when you can very easily do it in CSS.

Comment: choice is totally yours no problem :). But i guess jquery provides desired effect with very less code and efficiency, so i have suggested. But as i told final decision is totally yours. :) ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Not quite what I am after - I want more than one element to change not just the one.

Comment: @SteveDavies i have added change effect for title as well as grey area, what other element you want to be changed ?

Answer (score 0):

you wont be able to use a disjointed rollover like this with css, only javascript would be able to look at state of another element and apply elsewhere on conditions etc. If it was a child of it then of course it can - the below demonstrates this.
You coud use:-

```
.sm-gutter:hover, .sm-gutter:hover h3 span{
  background:purple;
}
```

Could this be of use instead, sticking with a css solution?

Comment: Hi Jamie, how would I impliment this?

Comment: Sorry not sure I follow? Can you add the css i provided to your solution?

Comment: You would need to remove the other hover references to keep your css clean and negate the need for overwriting other css calls - please note i used purple so you can see it working.